# Print output missing sides

Tags: creality-ender-3, ultimaker-cura, troubleshooting, slicing, infill

I tried to print my first object, which is the calibration cube downloaded from here, [XYZ 20mm Calibration Cube](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1278865).

However, the output has a visible infill on all sides:

[image: Photo of calibration cube with visible infill on all sides]

I think this is because some settings are not correct in the slicer.

I am using:

- Printer: Ender 3
- Slicer: Ultimaker Cura 5.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like perimeters and solid layers are not set in the Slicer. Make sure that these settings are greater than zero:

[image: Settings to set in the slicer]

Comment: That worked. Got a perfect cube. Thanks :)